# Finding Correct Size Wheel for Bike

Tags: wheels, hub, wheel-truing

I am looking to replace the stock wheelset on my [2009 Jamis Aurora](http://www.jamisbikes.com/usa/thebikes/pdfs/09_aurora.pdf).  I'm looking to replace wheels because I have a number of spokes break over the wheel lifetime and now my rear wheel is only in true from my own periodic adjustments, which are needed with increasing frequency.  The LBS indicated that wheel replacement would be more economical than wheel repair.

For compatibility considerations, I am looking at the following variables

1. spacing (my stock hubs are shimano tiagras.  I think the spacing is 130mm for both)
2. tire diameter (700)
3. cassette compatibility (SRAM Powerglide 950, 9-speed, 11-32)
4. Tire compatibility (I current roll on 35 front 32 rear)

Are there additional variables that I need to consider from a compatibility standpoint? I'm looking at the [Vuelta Corsa HD Road Wheelset](http://www.nashbar.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?productId=506872&storeId=10053&catalogId=10052&langId=-1) because it is affordable and the reviews indicate that they're reliable.

Am I correct in thinking this is a compatible choice?  Are there other variables that I need to consider?  And is this a poor choice?  I know a lot of people advocate hand-built wheels.

Comment: The rim width is listed as 20mm (but they don't specify whether it is exterior width or interior width...vendors rarely do and I don't know why.) It is likely the exterior width, in which case fitting a 35mm wide tire might challenging - in my experience rims of that width tend to top out at 32mm before it balloons the tire out too much and makes seating it difficult.

Comment: Also, what kind of riding do you do with your bike? Do you tour with it at all?

Comment: Alternatively, your hub is probably still in decent shape. It might be nice to buy some decent rims and build up wheels to your exact need.

Comment: If it's marketed as a road bike, it probably means the inner width.

Comment: @Wtharper Thanks -- all good comments.  I use the bike for commuting and light touring only (< 30 lb load) but I weigh about 200 as well.  alxndr  The bike is technically a touring bike, not road, so I wasn't sure what convention is used to specify rim size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the weight of you + your bike + your load should be a factor. At 200 + 28 + 30 lbs, your looking at close to 300 lbs. Consider 32h in the front and 36h in the rear.

For 32mm tires, look for rims that are 15-19mm wide inside, and for 35mm tires look for 17-21 mm wide.

I'm the same weight and have chosen 32h/36h but ride 38mm tires both front and back on 22m wide rims.

The wheels you link to meet those specs, so good choice (except for them not being in stock yet).